# Interface and implementation design structure?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inner-classes

I'm quite new to designing large programs in C++. I'm writing series of operations, each of which have their own class, which will be invoked by the `ProcessMgr` class.

I'm using `ProcessMgr` as an interface class, from which each operation can be invoked:

```
class ProcessMgr
{
 private:
   class OperationOne;
   class OperationTwo;
   class OperationThree;
}

class ProcessMgr::OperationOne 
{
 public:
   ...
};
class ProcessMgr::OperationTwo
{
 public:
  ...
};
class ProcessMgr::OperationThree
{
 public:
  ...
};
```

This enables me to control the types of access to the `Operation` classes, therefore not exposing much of their underlying code.

**It's important that the user of this code can only interact with the `Operation` classes in specific ways and not have complete access to all the contents of the `Operations` classes.**

My questions:

1) Is this a good approach to designing large programs? Are most libraries, such as CURL, structured in this way?

2) Are there better/more efficient methods of separating interface and implementation?

Comment: The overall design of any program depends on many variables, but I think it would be easier to help you understand the best design if you describe the purpose of the code

Comment: Not a C++ programmer here but how can 4 classes have the same name? Is this a C++ thing? It completely threw me off..

Comment: Updated questions @ZivS

Comment: Isn't this question more suited for http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: http://wiki.c2.com/?PimplIdiom

Comment: @CKing what do you mean??

Comment: @peval27 Correct me if I am wrong but there are 4 classes with the name `ProcessMgr` in the same name space in the code provided above. How is that not an issue in C++? Has the OP accidently interchanged the class names while inheriting?

Comment: @Laszlo when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @CKing No. It's not inheritance, it's about [nested types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types) Inside ProcessMgr OP has forward declared the classes, outside OP has defined the nested classes. It's the C++ way to decouple declaration and definition (AKA header/cpp files)

Comment: @BabraCunningham You said this should be a public interface to use. However in the example, there aren't public methods. Either it's not clear the question or I haven't understood.

Comment: @peval27 Got it. Thanks for the link. I didn't know what it was called so couldn't figure it out my self :)

Comment: @CKing no problem. single colon means derive, two colons is the scope resolution operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A normal Interface in C++ (or other OOP languages) provides the definitions. The "operation-classes" must be derived from the interface, so that you decouple the implementation from the client. This principle is called the [Dependency inversion principle(DIP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

A common UML-diagram from the DIP looks like the following:
[image]

Since the Client is just familiar with the Interface, you can control the access to the specific subclasses.
An Implementation could look like this:

```
class ProcessMgr {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virutal void bar() = 0;
}

class Operation1 : public ProcessMgr {
    virtual void foo() {  ...  }
    virtual void bar() {  ...  }
}

class Operation2 : public ProcessMgr {
    virtual void foo() {  ...  }
    virtual void bar() {  ...  }
}
```

The DIP is a principle from a series of very good principles, called [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). To design big projects, there is much more to do and learn. But the SOLID-principles are a good start to understand how to design software applications.